# What's the right way to verbalize -x in English?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

1. In mathematics, when the symbol says "-3", am I correct in saying that it can be pronounced as "negative three" or "minus three"?
2. When the symbol is "-x", can we still read it as "negative x" OR "minus x"? Or does the change of meaning necessitates the change of the name of the symbol?

Comment: All the terminologies you mentioned are acceptable.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): ["Negative" versus "Minus"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/157127/409). Also, a site search for [`negative minus`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=negative+minus) yields over 1300 results, some of which may be relevant.

Comment: If you needed to pick one or the other, "negative x" has a slightly more professional sound to it, but either one is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: How would you verbalize this expression? $a-(-b)$

Comment: Quoting from my Answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3889774/21813): Would you read 7=-(-7) as “*negative* negative 7” versus “minus minus 7”?